# FatalErrorException in productController.php line 16: Class 'App\Product' not found Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel just displaying all the data of a single table using model named 'Product.php' inside my 'app' folder. Unfortunatly i'm getting above error while doing so. Following is the controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;

use App\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class productController extends Controller
{

    function show(){

         return Product::all();
    }


}
```

and model code is following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class products extends Model
{
    protected $table='product';
}
```

Comment: Do a `composer dump-autoload` for starters. Make sure the namespace is indeed correct and that the file itself is located in said namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two mistakes:
1) remove letter "s".
2) Add first Upper case

```
...
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table='product';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a Model always use

```
php artisan make:model your_model_name
```

And your mistake is in your spelling

```
class products extends Model
```

It should be

```
class Product extends Model
```